# converting a dictionary with with multi values for each key to dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

I am new to Python and pandas. I am trying to convert a key with multiple values to dataframe. Below is the example data.

```
    Out[]: {a: [1, 2, 3], b: [11, 22, 33], 
         c: [111, 222, 333], d: [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444}
```

I have tried following pieces of code:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_name, orient = "index")
    df1
```

Or

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict_name)
```

But, I am not getting the out of what I want, I think I need to loop through the values or something, please help. The output I exepect:

```
      col_name1     col_name2
    0 a             1
    1 a             2
    2 a             3
    3 b             11 
    4 b             22
    5 b             33
    6 c             111
    and so on...
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshaping, if necessary [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and convert to `int`, last create `column` from `MultiIndex` by double [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_name, orient = "index")
       .sort_index()
       .stack()
       .astype(int)
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .reset_index()
df.columns = ['col_name1','col_name2']
print (df)
   col_name1  col_name2
0          a          1
1          a          2
2          a          3
3          b         11
4          b         22
5          b         33
6          c        111
7          c        222
8          c        333
9          d       1111
10         d       2222
11         d       3333
12         d       4444
```